# For loop - copy multiple files and rename extension in different dir

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I want to copy all `.txt` extension files from `copy_loc` directory to `past_loc` directory with `.hml` extension.

I do'nt want to move files, just copy to new location with `.hml` extension.

```
past_loc="/Users/Desktop/newdir"
copy_loc="/Users/Desktop/*.txt"

for file in $copy_loc; do
   scp "$file" "$(basename "$file" .txt).hml"
done
```

Issue: All `.hml` files are copied to the directory from where I am running this script and not to the `past_loc` directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the below :

```
for file in $copy_loc; 
do 
  filename=$(basename -- "$file" .txt)
  cp "$file" "$past_loc"/"$filename".hml 
done
```

Also just note that since you're not copying to a remote machine, you should be using `cp` and not `scp`

Comment: `basename` can remove the extension as well; `filename=$(basename -- "$file" .txt)`

Comment: Maybe also highlight that `cp` is the correct command, not `scp`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using parameter expansion. And hey, perhaps an array. :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sources=( /path/to/*.txt )

for file in "${sources[@]}"; do
   cp "$file" "/path/to/target/${file%.txt}.htm"
done
```

Parameter expansion allows you to avoid running text through a pipe in command substitution. It's lighter-weight.

Note that `scp` is **s**ecure **c**o**p**y. You don't need that when you're copying from and to the same filesystem.

Comment: What's the point of `sources`? Seems cleaner to do `for file in /path/to/*.txt; do ...`